# Getting Input in one Line Inside a Loop

Tags: c

I am working on a c programming problem. In the problem I have to get
two chars in one line. I have to repeat the process for n times. consider the following code:

```
char c[100],p[100];
int n;
scanf("%d",&n);
for(int i=0; i<n; i++)
    scanf("%c %c", &c[i], &p[i]);
```

I used this code to get the value of n, and then get the values in one line for the array of c and p. But I am getting some unexpected result and I don't know the reason. Need help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
scanf("%c %c", &c[i], &p[i]);
```

should be

```
scanf(" %c %c", &c[i], &p[i]);
```

There is a newline character at the end of input value `n` so you need to ignore it by placing a space before `%c`

Note the value of n should be `n<=100` else you have array out of bound access.

Make sure you null terminate the strings once the characters are scanned or have

```
char c[100] = "";
char p[100] = "";
```

In C a valid string should be null terminated.

If you are looking for a VLA(Variable length array) based on the size of `n` then have your array as

```
scanf("%d",&n);
char c[n];
char p[n];
for(int i=0; i<n-1; i++)
scanf(" %c %c", &c[i], &p[i]);
```

Comment: saw your edit for VLA size safety, deleting my comment (will delete this one too, at some point after you've had time to see it - this comment adds no value to your answer)

Answer (score 0):

You have to store the null value after reading characters into the character array.

```
char c[100],p[100];
int n;
scanf("%d",&n);
for(int i=0; i<n; i++)
    scanf("%c %c", &c[i], &p[i]);
c[i] = '\0';
p[i] = '\0';
```

Comment: Objection, your honor! Assuming facts not in evidence.  (I do not see a `printf`, `puts` or similar anywhere.  For all we know, OP might be using `putchar` in a loop for output.  Actually, OP says nothing about output at all - inputs could be used for something else.  How do we even know it has to be a nul-terminated string?).

Comment: I don't need a null character as I don't need do consider the array as a string. Although, I have understood the problem. It was newline character as gopi explained. Thanks :-)